# Equivalence of parallel transport, connection and covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

Here by connection I mean the horizontal distribution. I hear about these three notions are equivalent, i.e. given one we can recover another.

In the textbook of Riemannian geometry I have read, usually the existence of covariant derivative is proved to be exist, and then parallel transport. But there is nothing about horizontal distribution. So I would like to know whether there is any reference shows these three notions are equivalent(thoroughly). Thanks!

Comment: I sincerely recommend you a very hard book: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.5390v2.pdf It will give you a very extensive overview about the theme...

Comment: Kobayashi and Nomizu discuss connections defined by horizontal distributions.